# QEMU: "Why did my PC restart"

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

After installing QEMU and putting the Windows 10 iso file in the same directory as where I downloaded QEMU, I ran these commands:

`qemu-img.exe create -f qcow2 -o cluster_size=2M win10.qcow2 50G`

`qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom win10.iso -m 2048 win10.qcow2`

After saying "loading...", it told me "Why did my PC restart?". https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QDrS.png

After clicking on "next", it did the same thing again; brought me to the "why did my pc restart?" page. How do I make it install Windows 10?

I have virtualization turned on in the BIOS.

Comment: What is the exact make and model of your CPU? You may have configured the VM in a way that is incompatible with Windows 10.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as the situation is too unclear for it to remain.

Comment: @Daniel B

Device name (this may be personal info)
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz
Installed RAM 8.00 GB (7.88 GB usable)
Device ID (this may be personal info)
Product ID (this may be personal info)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch Pen and touch support with 10 touch points

Comment: If add this information to your question, it’s better readable. The CPU is quite new, so that can’t be the problem. Were did you obtain the Windows binaries for QEMU? What about the Windows 10 ISO? Do you know for which Windows it is? I’ll try to reproduce.

Comment: I got QEMU from here https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/
I got Windows 10 from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Having downloaded QEMU 5.2.0 (`qemu-w64-setup-20210208.exe`) and Windows 10 20H2 x64 English (SHA1 `69a1739609c1059fdd2e0688891bf59a78413c6b`), I can start the Windows installation without problems. My QEMU window looks totally different (missing icons). Please clarify which version(s) you have.

Comment: I have the newest version of QEMU and Windows 10. :/

Comment: I did that but got the same issue